# Get a previous date based on a future date using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ideally what i would like to do is take an input field attach a datepicker to it have someone pick a future date in time for example. [today is 08/09/2013 at the time of writing this and get 07/31/2013 in return.]

I want for no matter what date is picked, the input field using javascript, will always default the value to the Wednesday prior to the week in-which was the initial selected date value.

```
function getWednesday(date) {
    var d = (date.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : date.getDay() - 3);
    date.setTime(date.getTime() - (d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return date;
}
```

This will only return the Wednesday of the current week. My understanding of the javascript functions getDay will only return 0-6 representing sun-sat. setTime function takes a string of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 and convert to a actual date in time and getTime does the exact opposite. I'm not sure im taking the right approch to have a solid solution to the problem. Thanks in Advance for any help

Comment: I removed the C#/MVC tags - I know you're obviously using these in your project but they are unrelated to your question :)

Comment: There are many great libraries for dates, such as DataJS and momentJS, do you want to incorporate those or do you want a vanilla solution?

Comment: Would this datepicker you mention be a jQuery UI datepicker? If so you should specify that, as many datepickers have date parsing abilities built in !

Comment: @adeneo it is a jQuery UI datepicker. but i want to use a JavaScript function as i understand that there are built in functions and it might be easier to achieve a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here's the most clever way I can think of:

```
function prevWed(inDate){
  var adder=(3-inDate.getDay());
  var d=new Date(inDate.getFullYear(), inDate.getMonth(), inDate.getDate() + adder - 7);
  return d
}
```

even smaller:

```
return new Date(inDate.getFullYear(), inDate.getMonth(), inDate.getDate() + (3-inDate.getDay()) - 7);
```

Will this work?

Comment: Awesome! My first chosen answer! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak your function to include this:

```
function getWednesday(date) {
    var d = (date.getDay() == 0 ? 6 : date.getDay() - 3);
    date.setTime(date.getTime() - (d * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate()-7);
}
alert(getWednesday(new Date()));
```

I think that should work.

Comment: No it does not do what the OP wants. This gets you 24th of July if you make some adjustments to your code (`getMonths()` should be `getMonth()`).

Comment: Hmm - this one returns 7/31 in a TryIt editor on w3schools.com - I wonder if I didn't misread the OP's request - and thanks for the typo - It's been that kind of day ;-)

Comment: @user1182988 on sunday it goes to the previous monday?

Comment: Yes, my code was written on the assumption that "This will only return the Wednesday of the current week." If that's true then the function will work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
var wednesday = new Date(date.setDate(date.getDate() - ((date.getDay() == 0 ? 7 : date.getDay()) + 4)));
```

Counts the number of the day of today (5) + the number of days to subtract from last week to get to Wednesday.

Comment: What about months with a Sunday as first day?

Answer (score 0):

```
            var d = date.getDay();
        if (d == 0) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) + 86400000 * 3);
            return date;
        }
        else if (d == 1) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) + 86400000 * 2);
            return date;
        }
        else if (d == 2) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) + 86400000 );
            return date;
        }
        else if (d == 4) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) - 86400000 );
            return date;
        }
        else if (d == 5) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) - 86400000 * 2);
            return date;
        }
        else if (d == 6) {
            date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) - 86400000 * 3);
            return date;
        }
        else date.setTime(date.getTime() - 604800000);
        return date;
```

This actually get the solution i want a bit clunky thought...lol

Comment: You are aware that this is like, one line? `date.setTime((date.getTime() - 604800000) + 86400000 * (3 - date.getDay());`

Answer (score 0):

Thats should get you the previous wed of any given date and time

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/D3yYK/2/)

```
var x = new Date('8/1/2013') ;
var wed ;
for(var i=7 ; i > 0 ; i--){
    var myday = x.getTime() - (i * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ;
    var d = new Date(myday) ;

    if(!!~String(d).indexOf('Wed')) wed = d  

}
 console.log(wed) ;
```